# "#include <avr/eeprom.h>" in Arduino-IDE?

Tags: arduino, include, esp8266, arduino-ide, eeprom

After a long time I tried to get back in Arduino Programming. But with my old code I get the following error:

```
 fatal error: avr/eeprom.h: No such file or directory
 #include <avr/eeprom.h>
            ^
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
```

So why doesn't he find the avr library. Do I need to install it manually? And where can I find a download of it?

Comment: For which board? That's the most important information in this case. Also Arduino IDE version wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I use the newest release of the ide (1.8.5) the board is a ESP8266 (lolin v3) and the code i try to get working is the receive part here: http://www.14core.com/wiring-the-cc1101-1ghz-lss-low-power-spi-interface-spring-coil-transceiver-3052-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<avr/eeprom.h>` is available only for the AVR architecture. It's not possible to use it on other MCU architectures.

And `ESP8266` is definitely completely different MCU architecture.